# Does illicit payments qualify as transaction costs?

Tags: transaction-costs

In countries where corruption run deep to the point it is not considered illegal; can such payments be considered as transaction costs?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, corruption can be considered transaction cost.

You can read about that in the paper [*Honor among Thieves: A Transaction-Cost Interpretation of Corruption in Third World Countries*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/business-ethics-quarterly/article/abs/honor-among-thieves-a-transactioncost-interpretation-of-corruption-in-third-world-countries/9CCE993C589C455D84C53FB7A76424A7) by Bryan W. Husted (Business Ethics Quarterly, Volume 4, Issue 1, January 1994, pp. 17-27)